# selecting correct string

Tags: python

I am writing an if statement, and while it selects the correct line, I would like the data to be associated with it to start two lines below.

This is my current code:

```
 for l in message.splitlines():
            q = l.strip().split(" ")                
            if q[0] == 'onion-key':
                format = ['onion-key']
                data = dict(zip(format, q[0:]))
                idt= data['onion-key']
                print idt
```

Here is the string in which I am taking the information from:

```
onion-key
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBANRir84jtEQP6tqhTubbcs+EWHgzxBdU6QG0HV+3tZ5m4JPo/hTEZd+I
2kvmtYZZ3WdxXhcISkaa476ArbKL6BmPCG1h+yeMko6yhu+gWk/40RE0dHKoPcRg
kV4sXerZezXnB4e1d8FHyDiPmgY6LHvfXZqn19xDRx11/h92/kb5AgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
service-key
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBALVjBUTK0wkWVjh+liiBVrweZskPGiIynKxDy+c4XBnEYqm5dcnifEDf
lgyNxOkv0gwYwrt4gS0+t0fyNARq+u6/MEJCEjgc8aS77gMLy/BQgkQHmLE6adjc
tQCDfklbblobq3YrTCQTgECuG91ol3okMM3M4gYPuGS/7MJmAyonAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

What I am trying to do is select where `onion-key` is mentioned and then, in a dictionary, map the begin RSA key to the End RSA key.

How can I achieve this?

Output would be a dictionary where `onion-key` is the key and the value is the following:

```
MIGJAoGBANRir84jtEQP6tqhTubbcs+EWHgzxBdU6QG0HV+3tZ5m4JPo/hTEZd+I
2kvmtYZZ3WdxXhcISkaa476ArbKL6BmPCG1h+yeMko6yhu+gWk/40RE0dHKoPcRg
kV4sXerZezXnB4e1d8FHyDiPmgY6LHvfXZqn19xDRx11/h92/kb5AgMBAAE=
```

.

```
dict{onion-key,     MIGJAoGBANRir84jtEQP6tqhTubbcs+EWHgzxBdU6QG0HV+3tZ5m4JPo/hTEZd+I
    2kvmtYZZ3WdxXhcISkaa476ArbKL6BmPCG1h+yeMko6yhu+gWk/40RE0dHKoPcRg
    kV4sXerZezXnB4e1d8FHyDiPmgY6LHvfXZqn19xDRx11/h92/kb5AgMBAAE=}
```

Comment: Please give example output

Comment: example have been added above

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like work for a regex.

```
import re
pat=re.compile(r"onion-key\s?-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\s?(.*?)\s?-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", re.DOTALL)
result = {'onion-key': key for key in pat.findall(message)}
```

If you want to find the service-key too:

```
pat = re.compile(r"([\w-]+)\s-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\s(.*?)\s-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", re.DOTALL)
result = dict(pat.findall(message))
```

Or if you have a whole bunch of them:

```
results = [dict(pair) for pair in zip(*[iter(pat.findall(message))]*2)]
```

Comment: Do you need to grab the service-key too?

Comment: Yes i do, and thanks that is working fine, however in the doc i have three onion-keys, how can i grab all three at the same time

Comment: @user2061913 gimme a minute I'll come up with something

Comment: @user2061913 there you go

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('yourfile')
d = {}
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.endswith("-key"):
        current_key = line
        d[current_key] = ""
    elif "-----" not in line:
        d[current_key] += line
```

Comment: What if one of the key value lines happens to end with `"-key"` or contain `"-----"`?

Comment: Is the '-' character allowed in ssh key value?

Comment: list' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: Actually the values look base64 encoded, which means they wouldn't have any `"-"` characters, so what you have looks OK in that respect -- I wasn't the down-voter, BTW.

Comment: @user2061913: As written, `line` would be a string not a `list` object.

Comment: @martineau I based my answer on that restriction. No problem anyway :)